# css file not visible - file not being styled

Tags: html, css

In my html file I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Although he css file is not visible so the styling doesn't occur, html is plain.

The file structure is following:

filename

```
  -css
     -styles
  -index.html
```

I also do not have any 404 errors in my console .log

Can you please try to help me to figure out why don't I see any styling?

Comment: You should check how to ask a question properly, this is unclear and you may not get the desired answer.

Comment: Hey, sorry i cannot not understand what you want. 
please explain in more detail.

Comment: @NemanjaG thank you, I clarified :)

Comment: @PaulineK try adding type="text/css" to link

Comment: @NemanjaG I did :( It doesn't work :((

Answer (score 0):

you should link it like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">`

please be sure that your file is named `styles.css` and not `style.css`

you can look in your browser network tab and see if the file is loaded.

Comment: thank you :) I can see in the network tab that the styles file is loaded there, but the website still is plain. Do you know what could be the issue in this case?

Answer (score -1):

This is an example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) and your html should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Just make sure you have the correct path to the css file. Example, try `./css/styles.css`

Comment: <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Obstacle Course 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
      </head>
        <body> etc.... still doesnt work. :(